# How can I construct a PlasmaContainsRequest if I don't know how to get a WIPOffset object?

Tags: rust, flatbuffers

How can I construct a `PlasmaContainsRequest` object, since I don't know how to get a `WIPOffset` object to construct a `PlasmaContainsRequestArgs` object?

I used `flatc` 1.10.0 to generate this Rust code:

```
impl<'a> PlasmaContainsRequest<'a> {
    #[inline]
    pub fn init_from_table(table: flatbuffers::Table<'a>) -> Self {
        PlasmaContainsRequest { _tab: table }
    }
    #[allow(unused_mut)]
    pub fn create<'bldr: 'args, 'args: 'mut_bldr, 'mut_bldr>(
        _fbb: &'mut_bldr mut flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder<'bldr>,
        args: &'args PlasmaContainsRequestArgs<'args>,
    ) -> flatbuffers::WIPOffset<PlasmaContainsRequest<'bldr>> {
        let mut builder = PlasmaContainsRequestBuilder::new(_fbb);
        if let Some(x) = args.object_id {
            builder.add_object_id(x);
        }
        builder.finish()
    }

    pub const VT_OBJECT_ID: flatbuffers::VOffsetT = 4;

    #[inline]
    pub fn object_id(&self) -> Option<&'a str> {
        self._tab
            .get::<flatbuffers::ForwardsUOffset<&str>>(PlasmaContainsRequest::VT_OBJECT_ID, None)
    }
}

pub struct PlasmaContainsRequestArgs<'a> {
    pub object_id: Option<flatbuffers::WIPOffset<&'a str>>,
}
impl<'a> Default for PlasmaContainsRequestArgs<'a> {
    #[inline]
    fn default() -> Self {
        PlasmaContainsRequestArgs { object_id: None }
    }
}
```

Comment: and if I call `finish` on a `FlatBufferBuilder` object, I also need to pass a `WIPOffset` argument.  I do not know what it is, and it is not needed in other languages such as c++

Comment: WIPOffset is similar to Offset<> in C++, you should get it from any calls that create tables, there is like a `CreatePlasmaContainsRequest` or similar. Sorry not super familiar with the Rust API.